# Getting android:exported error even if it exists in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic6

After I installed `cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing` plugin into my ionic cordova project I am getting the below error when executed build command:

```
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
D:\Project\@Codes Repos\Ionic6-cordova\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
```

If I check my `AndroidManifest.xml` file, the `activity` tag already has the `android:exported="true"` property.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.test.testproj" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:exported="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:exported="true" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileOpener2.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="io.github.pwlin.cordova.plugins.fileopener2.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/opener_paths" />
        </provider>
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.ShareChooserPendingIntent">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.sharing.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/sharing_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
</manifest>
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68683614) solution but not working.

**Ionic Info**

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.19.0 (C:\Users\CGauns\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.15.0\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.1.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 13.2.6
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 13.2.6
   @angular/cli                  : 13.2.6
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 10.1.2
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 22 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : 0.15.4
   native-run (update available: 1.6.0) : 1.5.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (D:\Android\sdk)
   NodeJS            : v16.15.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 8.5.5
   OS                : Windows 10
```